# how to group in sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to group the rows of the table based on a property in sap.ui.table.Table
I tried using how we do in sap.m.table.
But it is not working.

```
<ui:Table rows="{
                    path : '/EtyVacStockItmSet',
        sorter : {
            path : 'FacilityType',
            group : true
        }}" selectionMode="Single" ariaLabelledBy="title" id="productsTable">
```

Comment: have you enabled  `data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"` ?

Comment: I don't have index.html .. how to do it in manifest.json

Comment: You have sap.ui.table.Table. It has different way of applying sorter. What you have done works for sap.m.Table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to sap.ui.table.Table like sap.m.Table..however we can add grouping by adding column menu for sorting...see [sample](http://jsbin.com/vuvotaqido/1/edit?html,output)

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
            visibleRowCount: 10,enableGrouping:true,
          rows:"{/rows}",
          columns:[
            new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: "firstName",
               template: "firstName",
              //sorted:true,sortProperty:"department",grouped:true
            }),
            new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: "lastName",
               template: "lastName",
             // sorted:true,sortProperty:"department",grouped:true
            }),
            new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: "department",
                template: "department",
              sorted:true,sortProperty:"department",//grouped:true
            })

          ]
        });
```